# Embedded Google Maps Street View shows black borders and issues under certain browser width and on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, google-street-view

I embedded a Google Maps Street View in my page using "gmap3" jQuery Plugin:

Under certain browser width and on mobiles, Street View shows a black border in the bottom and the image is deformed.

You can try it here by resizing the browser window down to about 400px: 
http://www.genovaperte.it/item/hostaia-del-missionario/

PS: in order to see the webpage you'll need username = webcompany and password = webcompany as the site is not online yet.

Already tested in many browsers and mobile phones with the same issue.
This happens both with the desktop Flash version and the HTML5 mobile version of the Google Street View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Google corrected the issue.